# After successful pip3 install, I still get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm installing a complex Python software project. 5 engineers worked on this for some years, but they are all gone now, so I need to figure this out on my own. I run:

```
/usr/local/bin/pipenv lock
```

And I get a long set of errors, one of which is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

So I run:

```
pip3 install ConfigParser
```

I get:

```
Collecting ConfigParser
Downloading configparser-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Installing collected packages: ConfigParser
Successfully installed ConfigParser-5.2.0
```

Then I repeat:

```
/usr/local/bin/pipenv lock
```

I get exactly the same set of errors:

```
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
```

And a long set of errors that look like this:

```
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/blueflow-c7ciKYpf/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_75c2812bb7024f2aac1a6aa1c5c2cef9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_75c2812bb7024f2aac1a6aa1c5c2cef9/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' --no-user-cfg egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-35pnz9zt
     cwd: /tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_75c2812bb7024f2aac1a6aa1c5c2cef9/
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_75c2812bb7024f2aac1a6aa1c5c2cef9/setup.py", line 225
    except Warning, w:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/blueflow-c7ciKYpf/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_418a10a77a924c508bc796a1db4c47ae/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_418a10a77a924c508bc796a1db4c47ae/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' --no-user-cfg egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-91fiybpm
     cwd: /tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_418a10a77a924c508bc796a1db4c47ae/
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pipenv-dmt2c0oj-build/psycopg2_418a10a77a924c508bc796a1db4c47ae/setup.py", line 50, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
----------------------------------------
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2 (from versions: 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.0.14, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4, 2.5.5, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.3.1, 2.7.3.2, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.6.1, 2.7.7, 2.8, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.8.5, 2.8.6, 2.9, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 743, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 711, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 693, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1385, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1106, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 884, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2
```

I'm thinking pipenv is using some paths that are different from wherever `pip3` installs things? How could I find out?

Comment: This looks like `python2` code - you will need to refactor it to `python3` - have a look at the `2to3` command.

Comment: create a virtualenv and start working on that project on it.

Comment: I believe this project is a complex mix of Python2 and Python3, but they had it working, so there must be some way to get it working. And refactoring the whole thing is not possible, it took 5 engineers 3 years to create, it would take me 10 years to refactor. But since it was working, I should be able to get it working.

Comment: @sahasrara62 -- I believe the install script created a virtualenv. I saw a success message in some of the text that scrolled by in the terminal. But how would I check that for sure?

Comment: @charlottesville check in the script if there is somethibng like `python -m virtualenv <env name>`, btw why no one who undertsand the project, apart from you?

Comment: All the engineers are gone. They worked on it for a few years but they left before I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to get traction on this problem was to add more and more to the PATH in my `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/pipenv:/usr/local/bin/"
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/:/root/.local/bin/"
export PATH="$PATH:/root/blueflow/blueflow/bin/"
```

And the same for the `ec2-user` of course.

Doing everything as root did simplify some of the problems, but of course it introduces great security risks.